# How to get duplicate values in all rows filtering by one column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Here is what my table looks like.

```
Person  Date      Entry
Person1 05-20-14  142
Person2 05-20-14  443
Person1 05-21-14  248    
Person1 05-21-14  142
```

I need two things.

First the number of times a Person made an entry for the first time.

I tried doing it with these queries. But the problem is I need this information per day.

That is if I query for 05/21, I need to see output

```
"Person1 1"
```

142 wont be included because it already exists.

In my query, I am filtering by date already, so I am not sure how to go out and search in the rest of the dates values. Here is what I have.

```
SELECT PERSON, Count(distinct Entry) 
from [table]
where date >= 05/21/2014
and date < 05/22/2014
group by person
order by person.
```

This gives me

```
  Person1 2
```

Both 248 and 142 are considered here. How do I look for 142 was an entry already made in previous dates. I am not very good at nested queries.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS you're using, as the answer to this is implementation-dependent.

Comment: question not so clear, could you provide what your output should be for some cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this solve your problem or give you an idea how inner query should be?

```
SELECT PERSON, Count(distinct Entry) 
from [table]
where date >= 05/21/2014
and date < 05/22/2014
  and Entry not in (select distinct entry from [table] where date <> 05/21/2014)
group by person
order by person.
```

in the above query i have just added an inner query to get the distinct entry from other dates

```
select distinct entry from [table] where date <> 05/21/2014
```

and i have added the where condition that the current result should not consider those entries by

```
and Entry not in (select distinct entry from [table] where date <> 05/21/2014)
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This helped. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For the first query, it sounds like you need something like this:

```
SELECT Person 
FROM sample
GROUP BY date, person
HAVING date = '05-21-2014'
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4653d/1

This might also help:

```
SELECT Person, date
FROM sample
GROUP BY date, person
ORDER BY date
```

Hopefully that helps, let me know if I am misunderstanding something..

Comment: Thanks for your response. This isn't what I was looking for.